# How do I send a unix-exe to my friend so he can run it by double clicking?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, xcode6, static-libraries

In OSX, when I double click on the program file (unix executable) in any directory on my computer, it runs just fine.  When my friend double clicks, also on OSX, it says it doesn't know what software to open it with.
I used Xcode to compile the program as a "command line tool" in C++.  I was told to use static libraries to solve this, but I have no idea how.

Comment: chmod the file to executable.

Answer (score 1):

How are you transferring it? Sometimes, the executable flag may get removed. Running "chmod +x */path/to/executable*" should fix it

Comment: Okay, it now knows it's an executable, but now it's looking for the GLFW .dylib from my computer instead of using the framework file that's in the same folder.  is there such a way to compile it to automatically look in the folder the executable is in?

Comment: I believe you need the lib in the exact same path: ("/path/to/dylib" instead of "/path/for/dylib") even if the exec and dylib is in the same folder

Comment: Are you saying to put the dylib in the build folder?

Comment: Put the dylib in the same folder as on the build machine. For example, if it's in /folder/dylib on the build machine, it also needs to be in /folder/dylib on the machine you are trying to run it.